# SQL To select Unique domain count for my subscribers?

Tags: sql

I am trying to identify the number of subscribers I have from each domain, yahoo, google, aol....

Here is what I came up with but it is not grouping as I thought it would

```
select SUBSTRING(EmailAddress, PATINDEX('%@%', EmailAddress) +1, LEN(EmailAddress) -PATINDEX('%@%', EmailAddress)) As [Domain], COUNT(SUBSTRING(EmailAddress, PATINDEX('%@%', EmailAddress) +1, LEN(EmailAddress) - PATINDEX('%@%', EmailAddress))) As [Count]
from Subscribers
GROUP BY EmailAddress
```

The results look like this

```
yahoo.com   1
gmail.com   1
yahoo.com   1
```

I want something more like this

```
yahoo.com   2
gmail.com   1
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are grouping by the `emailaddress` which is not the value of the `domain`. If the email address contains `john@yahoo.com` or `jim@yahoo.com`, since those are unique, when you group the count separates them.

If you want to group by the domain value, then you need to `GROUP BY` your computed formala for the domain:

```
select SUBSTRING(EmailAddress, PATINDEX('%@%', EmailAddress) +1, LEN(EmailAddress) -PATINDEX('%@%', EmailAddress)) As [Domain], 
  COUNT(SUBSTRING(EmailAddress, PATINDEX('%@%', EmailAddress) +1, LEN(EmailAddress) - PATINDEX('%@%', EmailAddress))) As [Count]
from Subscribers
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(EmailAddress, PATINDEX('%@%', EmailAddress) +1, LEN(EmailAddress) -PATINDEX('%@%', EmailAddress));
```

Or you can use a subquery to then group by the `domain` alias:

```
select domain,
  count(*) [count]
from
(
  select SUBSTRING(EmailAddress, PATINDEX('%@%', EmailAddress) +1, LEN(EmailAddress) -PATINDEX('%@%', EmailAddress)) As [Domain]
  from Subscribers
) d
group by domain;
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something like that. I had tried to group by Domain so at least I was on the right track, I did not know I had to add the formula. I will mark as answered in 12 minutes...